# General Confidence Interval Equation Confusion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, sampling, confidence-interval

I am stuck with a small issue (compared to others [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909908/why-sampling-without-replacement-gives-better-ci-performance), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2895345/confidence-intervals-are-my-statistical-inferences-correct) I am still stuck with) in generalizing CI for a good (i.e normally distributed) sampling distribution

If my normal approximation is described by $x$ (with sample mean $\overline{X}$ and sample SD $S = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$), I have,

$$
Pr(x-1.96\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \mu \leq x + 1.96\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}) = 0.95 \tag{1}
$$

Now, the probability area 0.025 in standard normal distribution Z, corresponds to $Z = -1.96$

So 
$$
Z_{0.025} = -1.96 \\
Z_{\frac{0.05}{2}} = -1.96
$$

With $\alpha$ as significance level, $1-\alpha = 0.95$, then $\alpha = 0.05$, So

$$
Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} = -1.96 \tag{2}
$$

Substituting $1$ in $2$, we get

$$
Pr(x+Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \mu \leq x - Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}) = 0.95 \tag{3}
$$

But books define the other way. For eg, in ["Probability and Statistical Inference"](http://www.nylxs.com/docs/thesis/sources/Probability%20and%20Statistical%20Inference%209ed%20%5B2015%5D.pdf) by Hogg $et. al$, it is defined as below (page 310)

$$
Pr(x-Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \mu \leq x + Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}) = 0.95 \tag{4}
$$

which implies

$$
Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} = 1.96 \tag{5}
$$

which is not true. The probability area covered at $Z = 1.96$ is $0.975$, That is,

$$
Z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}} = 1.96 \tag{6}
$$

So what am I missing?

**My take for now:**
Somehow unanimously the book authors (and many others), assume, the normal curve area for right tail, the alternate convention of how to read area. Like [here](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~rcs46/lectures_2015/14-bayes1/z-table.pdf). Then $Z_{0.025} = 1.96$ and all fall in place I suppose. I have been used reading area with left tail probabilities so far which I thought was the convention.

Comment: do you have a typo here $$Pr(x+Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \mu \leq x - Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}) = 0.95 \tag{3}$$ ?

Comment: I could not spot (its midnight, am already sleepy), can you please be more specific?

Comment: lower bound is greater than upper bound ?

Comment: yeah, thats part of the doubt, because in my derivation, I find, $Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ to be negative. Check equation $2$ in my post

Comment: No hold on. You're doing a two sided (tailed) test. $Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} > 0$ is a convention.

Comment: But for area of 0.025, the respective Z value is $Z = -1.96$, that is, the area covered from $Z=-\infty$ to $-1.96$ is 0.025, so $Z_{0.025} = -1.96$ which is $< 0$? For any Z value, the respective area is always from $-\infty$ to that value which is again a convention? By that convention, $Z=1.96$ covers an area of $0.975$, so $Z_{0.975} = 1.96$?

Comment: yeah $z = -1.96$ if you're looking at the left tail, i.e. $Pr( Z < -1.96) = 0.025$. Similarly $Pr(Z > 1.96) = 0.025$... 
In short, you're saying that $Pr(Z < 1.96) = 0.975$. It should be $Pr(Z > 1.96)$.